Python code can't close windows it opened
# Iterate over each sentence and its corresponding image
for sentence, image_path in zip(sentences, image_paths):
    # Open image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.text((10, 10), sentence, font=font, fill=text_color)  # Draw sentence text on image
    
    # Display image
    image.show()
    
    # Wait for 2 seconds
    time.sleep(2)
    
    # Speak sentence
    engine.say(sentence)
    engine.runAndWait()
    
    # Find window by title
    window_title = "Image"  # Update with the title of the image window
    window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
    if window != 0:  # Check if window handle is valid
        image_windows.append(window)
    else:
        print("Image window not found.")
    
# Close only the image windows opened by the script
for window_handle in image_windows:
    win32gui.PostMessage(window_handle, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)

When I run the code, the windows can't be closed and message "Image window not found" keeps showing up.
I understand the program could not find the right window ("Image"). It's probably the window it opened was not titled "Image".
I have no idea how to fix it.  I want the windows it opened to be closed automatically.

probably the window it opened was not titled "Image" Okay, then the obvious solution is to use the actual title of the window, instead of "Image".
